# Adding x-amz-expires to query authentication header gives error(AccessDenied)

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I am downloading assets from amazon server using Unity's WWW class.It works fine until I add x-amz-expires to header.I need the url to expire after some time.I am unable to understand,is it because of the format of the expiry date and time.Please help.

```
void Start()
{
    SendRequestToAmazonS3 (mFileName);
}


void SendRequestToAmazonS3(string inFileName)
{

    Dictionary<string,string> headers=new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string dateString =DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ") + "GMT";
    headers.Add("x-amz-date", dateString);

    System.Int32 tempTimestamp = (System.Int32)(System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10).Subtract(new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds; 
    string unixTimestamp = tempTimestamp.ToString();
    headers.Add ("x-amz-expires", unixTimestamp);  //works fine if I don't add this 

    string canonicalString = "GET\n\n\n\nx-amz-date:" + dateString + "\n/" + mBucketName + "/" + inFileName;
    // now encode the canonical string
    var utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    // create a hashing object
    HMACSHA1 signature = new HMACSHA1();
    // secretId is the hash key
    signature.Key = utf8.GetBytes(mSecretKey);
    byte[] bytes  = utf8.GetBytes(canonicalString);
    byte[] hashBytes = signature.ComputeHash(bytes);
    // convert the hash byte array into a base64 encoding
    string encodedCanonical = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

    // finally, this is the Authorization header.
    headers.Add("Authorization", "AWS " + mAccessKey + ":" + encodedCanonical);

    // The URL, either PATH_HOSTED or VIRTUAL_HOSTED, plus the item path in the bucket 
    string url = mAwsS3Url + inFileName;
    Debug.Log (url);

    WWW www = new WWW(url, null, headers);

    // Send the request in this coroutine so as not to wait busily
    StartCoroutine(WaitForDownload(www));
}



IEnumerator WaitForDownload(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;

    // Check for errors
    if(www.error==null)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes (Application.dataPath + "/assetsS3.zip", www.bytes);
        Debug.Log ("Transfer complete");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log ("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.x-am-expires must also be in the same format as date. 
string expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes (10).ToString ("ddd,dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ")+"GMT";

Comment: Good. How did you find out that the time is GMT instead of UTC?

Comment: Actually the whole procedure for signing and authentication is given in the the link  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html .Here I found out that time is UTC.I  followed the document and wrote the code...:)

Comment: Nice. When you finish making your API with `WWW`, I suggest you port it to `UnityWebRequest` The newest way of communicating with servers. It solves many problems `WWW` has. It is very likely `WWW` will be deprecated.  Don't worry about that now, just when you finish and the porting is easy if you read the link below. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html

Comment: Very useful documentation..Thanks for the info..:)